# How do I make this query display all the rows, even if they have NULLS for date?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query that pulls data from multiple tables.

```
SELECT ph.list_header_id
     ,phtl.name
     ,mtl.segment1
     ,mtl.description
     ,pl.list_price_uom_code
     ,pl.price_break_type_code
     ,pl.list_price
     ,ph.currency_code
     ,pl.start_date_active
     ,pl.end_date_active
    FROM qp_list_headers_b ph
    LEFT OUTER JOIN qp_list_headers_tl phtl ON phtl.list_header_id = ph.list_header_id
                                       AND phtl.language = userenv('LANG') 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN qp_list_lines pl ON pl.list_header_id = ph.list_header_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mtl_parameters mp ON mp.master_organization_id = mp.organization_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mtl_system_items_b mtl ON mtl.inventory_item_id = pl.inventory_item_id
                                      AND mtl.organization_id = mp.organization_id
    WHERE ph.list_header_id BETWEEN :p_header_id_start AND :p_header_id_end
    AND pl.start_date_active BETWEEN :p_start_date AND :p_end_date
```

The problem is that  if there's a null in the date, it doesn't pull that row ( and the same for also for other columns when they're null )

How do I fix this issue? thanks so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change the last condition from

```
AND pl.start_date_active BETWEEN :p_start_date AND :p_end_date
```

to

```
AND (
     pl.start_date_active IS NULL
     OR pl.start_date_active BETWEEN :p_start_date AND :p_end_date
)
```